# Preg_match not returning success

Tags: php, regex, match

When I try to match some user input code I always get 0 as returned value.

```
$input = $_POST['input'];
$look = '[a-zA-Z]';
preg_match($look,$input);
```

For some reason I always get 0 as return value, why?

Comment: You should use with slash `$look = '/^[a-zA-Z]+/';` and can use with `i` so insensitive like ``$look = '/^[a-z]+/i';``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of issues here in your regex:

1. Regex needs a delimiter so it should be `` `/[a-zA-Z]/' ``
2. You are probably more than single US English letter so better to use `+` modifier to match more than 1 letter
3. Not using start and end of line anchors can cause problems and you may get false positive from your `preg_match` call.

Combining all suggestions, you can use this regex:

```
$look = '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/';
```

OR

```
$look = '/^[a-z]+$/i';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$input = $_POST['input'];
$look = '/^[a-zA-Z]/';
preg_match($look,$input);
?>
```

See [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)